# Как на убунту интегрировать eclipse luna и apache2?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, eclipse

На убунту у меня установлены eclipse luna+pydev и apache2. Я хочу интегрировать свой апач в eclipse для тестирования web-приложений на python. Не могу найти решение этого трабла. Прошу помочь.

Comment: Что конкретно настраивать в питоновской части eclipse не скажу. А в апаче достаточно создать и настроить `VirtualHost`, у которого `DirectoryRoot` будет показывать в эклипсовский workspace. Соответственно, с точки зрения апача проекты будут жить по адресам `хттп://хост/каталог_проекта`

Comment: попробую - отпишусь. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Для klopp: При создании вирт.хост на каталог workspace меняются разрешения, которые дают возможность потом работать созданным вирт.хостам, но НЕ дают стартовать самому eclipse luna...такая трабла.

Comment: Да - перепроверил еще раз...выходит, что eclipse желает только единолично владеть своим workspace и если туда кто-то суется еще (типа апача) - он перестает стартовать. Пришлось мне все заново настраивать в eclipse luna+pydev )))

Comment: Что-то у вас не так, значит. У меня именно luna, никаких проблем с этим нет. Апачевский конфиг сейчас выложу.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Luna на Debian, Linux Mint и XP. Конфиги везде одинаковые, апач тоже. `/home/klopp/projects/` - это каталог с `workspace`. Всё работает так (конфиг минимально-общий, для остального есть `.htaccess` в проектах, но вполне рабочий):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  eclipse.local
    DocumentRoot /home/klopp/projects/

    <Directory /home/klopp/projects/>
        Require all granted
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/eclipse.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/eclipse.access.log common

</VirtualHost>
```

Соответственно, HTTP-доступ к проектам происходит по URL вида `http://eclipse.local/project_dir/`, что снаружи, что из самого Eclipse. Никаких проблем с запуском Eclipse нет.

---

Нарылось вот ещё что. В линуксах могут быть проблемы со внутренним браузером Eclipse. Если не вдаваться в подробности, то оно хочет не только всяких там `libwebkit*`, но и мозилловских библиотек. Основные моменты [описаны по этой ссылке](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux). Кратко: для версии 4.4.x качаем мозиллу (в моём случае это [mozilla-i686-pc-linux-gnu-1.7.12-gtk2+xft.tar.gz](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mozilla/releases/mozilla1.7.12/contrib/)). Распаковываем её куда-нибудь и в окружение (или в скрипт, запускающий Eclipse) добавляем:

```
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/куда_распаковали/mozilla
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Всё, внутренний браузер включается и можно работать с веб-приложениями прямо в Eclipse.

Comment: вы меня не совсем поняли. Вы объединили каталоги апача(для вирт. хоста) и раб. каталог эклипса. А я спрашивал про интеграцию апача в эклипс, те как получить апач в оснастке эклипса window-> preferences->server

Comment: я пытаюсь интегрировать апач в эклипс так, чтобы увидеть его в оснастке window -> preferences -> server и работать с ним прямо в IDE, а вы мне про объединение каталогов говорите. Но все равно спасибо ;) И кста - у меня таки эклипс не стартанул...после правки разрешений на каталог вирт. хоста(читай правки рабочего каталога эклипса). Вы по какой методе их создавали?

Comment: Так а какая конечная цель? Не совсем понятно, чем эти варианты отличаются. Тем более что у меня нет никакого `window -> preferences -> server` вообще.  А почему может не стартовать даже не представляю. В каких-то логах должно быть записано, наверное. Никак специально ничего не создавал, разрешений не менял, только в апачевском конфиге задал уже существующий воркспейс в качестве `DirectoryRoot`.

Comment: цель вот какая - получить в составе IDE интегрированный в IDE апач, чтобы там с ним и работать. Это делается в меню window -> preferences -> server  можно скачать с с eclipse marketplace сервера, но они по дефолту под жаву заточены, а я с апачем привык дело иметь и жаву не знаю.
Вы в линуксе работаете? Какая версия эклипса?
у меня Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: Да, Linux, такой же C/C++, потом обвешан средами для PHP, Perl и прочими наворотами. Отдельно сервер только в PHP настраивается.

Comment: ну тогда вы поймете меня )))  вы где свои приложения под php тестите? Вне эклипса?? А можно все там прямо в нем и делать, надо только интегрировать его туда - настроить server runtime environment - я про это. И делается это в оснастке server, в меню window -> preferences -> server

Comment: В эклипсе. А сервером - апач, с этими самыми настройками. Просто стоит галочка в глобальных настройках "use internal web browser".

Comment: Вот что ещё нарыл. "**How can I get the SWT internal browser to work under Linux?**
*Mylyn uses the Standard Widget Toolkit Browser, and users have experienced problems with the SWT Browser on Linux. This is not a Mylyn specific problem and also occurs if you try to use Eclipse’s Browser view. To test to see if your browser is properly configured, select Window → Show View → Other → General → Internal Web Browser, then try to load a web page.*"

Comment: Добавил в ответ, оно?

Comment: это про встроенный браузер, а мне про сервер надо. Спасибо брат, что упорно помогаешь,
но я вот про что (про сервер)
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwinstprf.html